# sharepoint alert customization

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I want to customize the sharepoint alert template.
I want in mail some fixed column of sharepoint and modified column

tried this link can able to restrict the column.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize the alert template stroed in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML"

In this template you have to provide fileds you like to show.

Please refer below given URL for more details

> http://www.alectang.com/blog/archive/2012/05/16/how-to-customise-sharepoint-alert-email-template.aspx

Comment: thanks for your response 
i am able to customize my alert template 
but i want some fixed column and modified column in alert
if i add any column name in <DigestNotificationExcludedFields> tag, that column is not coming in alert but if that column is modified in that case I need that column also in alert

Comment: You have to go for the Coding way. I am afraid I dont have this type of scenario in my experience

Comment: thanks 
but i want to apply this to my custom list.Is it possible to apply to the custom list through coding?

Comment: I think that is also possible to apply for custom list too